# Load User Control dynamically and Default Namespace

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-controls

In Silverlight, when you want to create a control dynamically, you must add the namespaces like this (as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189044(VS.95).aspx):

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007";
    XElement textBlock2 = new XElement(xmlns + "TextBlock",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"),
        ...
        );
```

My problem is that I have a user control in its own namespace, so I must write something like

```
XNamespace myxmlns = "mynamespace";
XElement myelem = new XElement(myxmlns + "MyCtrl", ...
```

I can then add aliased namespaces like that

```
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx")
```

but I can't figure out how to add the default namespace. I either get a compile error or a run-time error ("AG E PARSER MISSING DEFAULT NAMESPACE"), whatever I try.

I succeeded doing it with building a big string of what I need, but I would like to understand what I am missing.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [XNamespace docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx):

```
new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://http://www.adventure-works.com")
```

Just add it as an XAttribute.

Comment: Thanks, was too easy...  I love Linq to Xml, but the XNamespace is not that intuitive to me.